# rotating player camera on a sphere (javascript/three.js)

Tags: javascript, three.js, rotation, quaternions

I'm trying to have a player walk in a first person view on a planet, in three.js / javascript. In what I'm coding I want two things:

a) A player to properly move around a planet, with two movement types: rotation around himself (left-right and A/D buttons) and moving forward of backward (W/S buttons). With help from this thread https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/59298/walking-on-a-sphere I have managed to accomplish this.

b) A camera attached to the player should rotate horizontally (perpendicular to the plane the player is) when the player rotates around himself (A/D buttons) and the camera should move from 0 (nadir) to 180 (zenith) degrees - meaning player looks up and down, with the Arrow Up/ Arrow Down buttons (eventually with mouse, but that will come at a later point).

I have a problem with b, it correctly rotates initially but as the player moves on, the camera jumps in some other position.

In order to help me "debug" the problem I have created an `ArrowHelper` object which should eventually be our camera.

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">

        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache"/>
        <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1"/>
        <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache"/>
        <title>Planet</title>
        <link href="planet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <script src="../three.js/build/three.js"></script>
        <script src="../three.js/examples/js/libs/stats.min.js"></script>
        <script src="planet.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="divScreen">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

```js
var g_Game;
var g_Player;

window.onload = function () {
    initGame();
}

function initGame() {
    g_Game = new C_Game();

    g_Game.container = document.getElementById("divScreen");
    document.body.appendChild(g_Game.container);

    g_Game.scene = new THREE.Scene();

    g_Game.cameraPerspective = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 90, 1 * g_Game.aspect, 1, 10000 );
    g_Game.cameraPerspective.position.set(0.0, 0.0, g_Game.cameraDistance);

    //textures
    var earthTexture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( 'https://i.ibb.co/vYh8tLY/land-ocean-ice-cloud-2048.jpg' );

    g_Game.earth = new THREE.Mesh(
        new THREE.SphereBufferGeometry( 100, 128, 64 ),
        new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: earthTexture } )
    );
    g_Game.earth.position.set(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    g_Game.scene.add(g_Game.earth);

    g_Game.cubePlayer = new THREE.Mesh(
        new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry( 10, 10, 10 ),
        new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { wireframe: true } )
    );
    g_Game.cubePlayer.position.set(0.0, 0.0, 105.0);
    //g_Game.cubePlayer.add(g_Game.cameraPerspective);
    //g_Game.cameraPerspective.position.z = 0;
    g_Game.scene.add(g_Game.cubePlayer);

    var matrix = new THREE.Matrix4();
    matrix.extractRotation(g_Game.cubePlayer.matrix);
    var direction = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 1, 0 );
    direction.applyMatrix4(matrix);
    var dir = direction.normalize();

    var origin = g_Game.cubePlayer.position; //new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 105 );
    var length = 10;
    var color = 0xff0000;
    arrowHelper = new THREE.ArrowHelper( dir, origin, length, color );
    g_Game.cubeaxis = dir;
    g_Game.scene.add(arrowHelper);

    g_Game.cameraPerspective.lookAt(g_Game.earth.position);

    g_Game.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
    g_Game.renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
    g_Game.renderer.setSize( g_Game.SCREEN_WIDTH, g_Game.SCREEN_HEIGHT );
    g_Game.container.appendChild( g_Game.renderer.domElement );
    g_Game.renderer.autoClear = false;

    //g_Game.stats = new Stats();
    //g_Game.stats.showPanel(0);
    //g_Game.container.appendChild(g_Game.stats.dom);

    g_Player = new C_Player();
    g_Player.setspeed(0.08, 0.8);

    jsSetEventHandlers();

    animate();
}

function jsSetEventHandlers() {
    window.addEventListener("resize", onWindowResize, false );

    window.addEventListener("keydown", onKeyDown, false);
    window.addEventListener("keyup", onKeyUp, false);
};

// Keyboard key down
function onKeyDown(e) {
    switch (e.keyCode) {
        case 37: // Left
        case 65: // A
            g_Player.keyleft = true;
            break;
        case 38: // Up
            g_Player.keyarrowup = true;
            break;
        case 87: // W
            g_Player.keyup = true;
            break;
        case 39: // Right
        case 68: // D
            g_Player.keyright = true;
            break;
        case 40: // Down
            g_Player.keyarrowdown = true;
            break;
        case 83: // S
            g_Player.keydown = true;
            break;  
    }
}

// Keyboard key up
function onKeyUp(e) {
    switch (e.keyCode) {
        case 37: // Left
        case 65: // A
            g_Player.keyleft = false;
            break;
        case 38: // Up
            g_Player.keyarrowup = false;
            break;
        case 87: // W
            g_Player.keyup = false;
            break;
        case 39: // Right
        case 68: // D
            g_Player.keyright = false;
            break;
        case 40: // Down
            g_Player.keyarrowdown = false;
            break;
        case 83: // S
            g_Player.keydown = false;
            break;  
    }
}

function onWindowResize() {
    g_Game.SCREEN_WIDTH = window.innerWidth;
    g_Game.SCREEN_HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;
    g_Game.aspect = g_Game.SCREEN_WIDTH / g_Game.SCREEN_HEIGHT;
    g_Game.renderer.setSize(g_Game.SCREEN_WIDTH, g_Game.SCREEN_HEIGHT);
    g_Game.cameraPerspective.aspect = 1 * g_Game.aspect;
    g_Game.cameraPerspective.updateProjectionMatrix();
}

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    //g_Game.stats.begin();

    render();

    //g_Game.stats.end();
}

function render() {
    g_Player.update();
    g_Game.renderer.render(g_Game.scene, g_Game.cameraPerspective);
}

//Classes
var C_Player = function() {
    this.ANGULAR_SPEED_MOVEMENT = 0.8;
    this.ANGULAR_SPEED_ROTATION = 0.08;

    this.keyleft = false;
    this.keyright = false;
    this.keyup = false;
    this.keydown = false;
    this.keyarrowup = false;
    this.keyarrowdown = false;
    this.QuatKeyU;
    this.QuatKeyD;
    this.QuatKeyL;
    this.QuatKeyR;

    this.setspeed = function(speedM, speedR) {
        this.ANGULAR_SPEED_MOVEMENT = speedM;
        this.ANGULAR_SPEED_ROTATION = speedR;
        this.QuatKeyU = new THREE.Quaternion().setFromAxisAngle(new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 0), -(this.ANGULAR_SPEED_MOVEMENT*Math.PI) / 180);
        this.QuatKeyD = new THREE.Quaternion().setFromAxisAngle(new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 0),  (this.ANGULAR_SPEED_MOVEMENT*Math.PI) / 180);
        this.QuatKeyL = new THREE.Quaternion().setFromAxisAngle(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1),  (this.ANGULAR_SPEED_ROTATION*Math.PI) / 180);
        this.QuatKeyR = new THREE.Quaternion().setFromAxisAngle(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1), -(this.ANGULAR_SPEED_ROTATION*Math.PI) / 180);
    }

    var qx;
    var qy;
    var qz;
    var qw;
    var rotWorldMatrix;

    this.update = function(seconds) {
        var rlud = false;

        if (this.keyup) {
            g_Game.cubePlayer.quaternion.multiply(this.QuatKeyU);
            g_Game.cameraPerspective.quaternion.multiply(this.QuatKeyU);
            arrowHelper.quaternion.multiply(this.QuatKeyU);
            rlud = true;
        } else if (this.keydown) {
            g_Game.cubePlayer.quaternion.multiply(this.QuatKeyD);
            g_Game.cameraPerspective.quaternion.multiply(this.QuatKeyD);
            arrowHelper.quaternion.multiply(this.QuatKeyD);
            rlud = true;
        };
        if (this.keyleft) {
            g_Game.cubePlayer.quaternion.multiply(this.QuatKeyL);
            g_Game.cameraPerspective.quaternion.multiply(this.QuatKeyL);
            arrowHelper.quaternion.multiply(this.QuatKeyL);
            rlud = true;
        } else if (this.keyright) {
            g_Game.cubePlayer.quaternion.multiply(this.QuatKeyR);
            g_Game.cameraPerspective.quaternion.multiply(this.QuatKeyR);
            arrowHelper.quaternion.multiply(this.QuatKeyR);
            rlud = true;
        };

        if (rlud == true) {
            qx = g_Game.cubePlayer.quaternion.x;
            qy = g_Game.cubePlayer.quaternion.y;
            qz = g_Game.cubePlayer.quaternion.z;
            qw = g_Game.cubePlayer.quaternion.w;
            g_Game.cubePlayer.position.x = 2 * (qy * qw + qz * qx) * 105;
            g_Game.cubePlayer.position.y = 2 * (qz * qy - qw * qx) * 105;
            g_Game.cubePlayer.position.z = ((qz * qz + qw * qw) - (qx * qx + qy * qy)) * 105;

            qx = g_Game.cameraPerspective.quaternion.x;
            qy = g_Game.cameraPerspective.quaternion.y;
            qz = g_Game.cameraPerspective.quaternion.z;
            qw = g_Game.cameraPerspective.quaternion.w;
            g_Game.cameraPerspective.position.x = 2 * (qy * qw + qz * qx) * g_Game.cameraDistance;
            g_Game.cameraPerspective.position.y = 2 * (qz * qy - qw * qx) * g_Game.cameraDistance;
            g_Game.cameraPerspective.position.z = ((qz * qz + qw * qw) - (qx * qx + qy * qy)) * g_Game.cameraDistance;

            qx = arrowHelper.quaternion.x;
            qy = arrowHelper.quaternion.y;
            qz = arrowHelper.quaternion.z;
            qw = arrowHelper.quaternion.w;
            arrowHelper.position.x = 2 * (qy * qw + qz * qx) * 105;
            arrowHelper.position.y = 2 * (qz * qy - qw * qx) * 105;
            arrowHelper.position.z = ((qz * qz + qw * qw) - (qx * qx + qy * qy)) * 105;
        }

        if (this.keyarrowup) {
            var q = new THREE.Quaternion().setFromAxisAngle(new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 0), -(this.ANGULAR_SPEED_MOVEMENT*Math.PI*10) / 180);
            arrowHelper.quaternion.multiply(q);
            // TRIAL AND ERRORS HERE
            //arrowHelper.rotateOnWorldAxis(new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 0), -(this.ANGULAR_SPEED_MOVEMENT*Math.PI) / 180);
            //arrowHelper.rotateOnAxis(new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 0), -(this.ANGULAR_SPEED_MOVEMENT*Math.PI) / 180);
            /*      
            var matrix = new THREE.Matrix4();
            matrix.extractRotation(g_Game.cubePlayer.matrix);
            var direction = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 1, 0 );
            direction.applyMatrix4(matrix);
            var dir = direction.normalize();

            rotWorldMatrix = new THREE.Matrix4();
            rotWorldMatrix.makeRotationAxis(dir,  (this.ANGULAR_SPEED_ROTATION*Math.PI) / 180);
            rotWorldMatrix.multiply(g_Game.cubePlayer.matrix);
            g_Game.cubePlayer.matrix = rotWorldMatrix;
            g_Game.cubePlayer.rotation.setFromRotationMatrix(g_Game.cubePlayer.matrix);
            */
        }
        if (this.keyarrowdown) {
            var q = new THREE.Quaternion().setFromAxisAngle(new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 0), (this.ANGULAR_SPEED_MOVEMENT*Math.PI*10) / 180);
            arrowHelper.quaternion.multiply(q);
        }
    }
}

function C_Game() {
    this.SCREEN_WIDTH = window.innerWidth;
    this.SCREEN_HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;
    this.aspect = this.SCREEN_WIDTH / this.SCREEN_HEIGHT;
    this.container;
    this.stats;
    this.scene;
    this.renderer;
    this.earth;
    this.cubePlayer;
    this.controls;
    this.cameraPerspective;
    this.cameraDistance = 125;
    this.cubeaxis = new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 0);
}
```

```css
#divScreen {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0%;
    top: 0%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 0px;    
    background-color: #AACCFF;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
<div id="divScreen"></div>
```

I have made some efforts - I'm not really good with quaternions - but nothing seems to work. You can see at this point `// TRIAL AND ERRORS HERE` my various rotation efforts commented out as none of them will work (including the not commented out).

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/z18ctvme/3/

I would appreciate your help in solving this issue.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is the encoded in your question:

> A camera attached to the player [...]

Simplify things and attach `arrowHelper` to `g_Game.cubePlayer`. This means `arrowHelper` has to be a child of `g_Game.cubePlayer` rather than the [`THREE.Scene()`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/scenes/Scene):

```js
arrowHelper = new THREE.ArrowHelper( dir, new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 0 ), length, color );
g_Game.cubePlayer.add(arrowHelper);
```

This causes that `arrowHelper` is always at the same position relative to the `g_Game.cubePlayer`. In this case the relative position is `THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 0 )`.

`arrowHelper.quaternion` only contains the relative orientation of `arrowHelper`.
It is sufficient to update `arrowHelper.quaternion` in case of `this.keyarrowup` or `this.keyarrowdown`:

```js
this.update = function(seconds) {
    var rlud = false;

    if (this.keyup) {
        g_Game.cubePlayer.quaternion.multiply(this.QuatKeyU);
        g_Game.cameraPerspective.quaternion.multiply(this.QuatKeyU);
        rlud = true;
    } else if (this.keydown) {
        g_Game.cubePlayer.quaternion.multiply(this.QuatKeyD);
        g_Game.cameraPerspective.quaternion.multiply(this.QuatKeyD);
        rlud = true;
    };
    if (this.keyleft) {
        g_Game.cubePlayer.quaternion.multiply(this.QuatKeyL);
        g_Game.cameraPerspective.quaternion.multiply(this.QuatKeyL);
        rlud = true;
    } else if (this.keyright) {
        g_Game.cubePlayer.quaternion.multiply(this.QuatKeyR);
        g_Game.cameraPerspective.quaternion.multiply(this.QuatKeyR);
        rlud = true;
    };

    if (rlud == true) {
        qx = g_Game.cubePlayer.quaternion.x;
        qy = g_Game.cubePlayer.quaternion.y;
        qz = g_Game.cubePlayer.quaternion.z;
        qw = g_Game.cubePlayer.quaternion.w;
        g_Game.cubePlayer.position.x = 2 * (qy * qw + qz * qx) * 105;
        g_Game.cubePlayer.position.y = 2 * (qz * qy - qw * qx) * 105;
        g_Game.cubePlayer.position.z = ((qz * qz + qw * qw) - (qx * qx + qy * qy)) * 105;

        qx = g_Game.cameraPerspective.quaternion.x;
        qy = g_Game.cameraPerspective.quaternion.y;
        qz = g_Game.cameraPerspective.quaternion.z;
        qw = g_Game.cameraPerspective.quaternion.w;
        g_Game.cameraPerspective.position.x = 2 * (qy * qw + qz * qx) * g_Game.cameraDistance;
        g_Game.cameraPerspective.position.y = 2 * (qz * qy - qw * qx) * g_Game.cameraDistance;
        g_Game.cameraPerspective.position.z = ((qz * qz + qw * qw) - (qx * qx + qy * qy)) * g_Game.cameraDistance;
    }

    if (this.keyarrowup) {
        var q = new THREE.Quaternion().setFromAxisAngle(new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 0), -(this.ANGULAR_SPEED_MOVEMENT*Math.PI*10) / 180);
        arrowHelper.quaternion.multiply(q);
    }
    if (this.keyarrowdown) {
        var q = new THREE.Quaternion().setFromAxisAngle(new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 0), (this.ANGULAR_SPEED_MOVEMENT*Math.PI*10) / 180);
        arrowHelper.quaternion.multiply(q);
    }
}
```

See the example, where I applied the changes to your original code:

```js
var g_Game;
var g_Player;

window.onload = function () {
 initGame();
}

function initGame() {
 g_Game = new C_Game();

 g_Game.container = document.getElementById("divScreen");
 document.body.appendChild(g_Game.container);

 g_Game.scene = new THREE.Scene();

 g_Game.cameraPerspective = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 90, 1 * g_Game.aspect, 1, 10000 );
 g_Game.cameraPerspective.position.set(0.0, 0.0, g_Game.cameraDistance);
 
 //textures
 var earthTexture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( 'https://i.ibb.co/vYh8tLY/land-ocean-ice-cloud-2048.jpg' );
 
 g_Game.earth = new THREE.Mesh(
  new THREE.SphereBufferGeometry( 100, 128, 64 ),
  new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: earthTexture } )
 );
 g_Game.earth.position.set(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
 g_Game.scene.add(g_Game.earth);
 
 g_Game.cubePlayer = new THREE.Mesh(
  new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry( 10, 10, 10 ),
  new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { wireframe: true } )
 );
 g_Game.cubePlayer.position.set(0.0, 0.0, 105.0);
 //g_Game.cubePlayer.add(g_Game.cameraPerspective);
 //g_Game.cameraPerspective.position.z = 0;
 g_Game.scene.add(g_Game.cubePlayer);

 var matrix = new THREE.Matrix4();
 matrix.extractRotation(g_Game.cubePlayer.matrix);
 var direction = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 1, 0 );
 direction.applyMatrix4(matrix);
 var dir = direction.normalize();

 var origin = g_Game.cubePlayer.position; //new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 105 );
 var length = 10;
 var color = 0xff0000;
 
  arrowHelper = new THREE.ArrowHelper( dir, new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 0 ), length, color );
  g_Game.cubePlayer.add(arrowHelper);

 g_Game.cubeaxis = dir;


 g_Game.cameraPerspective.lookAt(g_Game.earth.position);

 g_Game.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
 g_Game.renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
 g_Game.renderer.setSize( g_Game.SCREEN_WIDTH, g_Game.SCREEN_HEIGHT );
 g_Game.container.appendChild( g_Game.renderer.domElement );
 g_Game.renderer.autoClear = false;

 //g_Game.stats = new Stats();
 //g_Game.stats.showPanel(0);
 //g_Game.container.appendChild(g_Game.stats.dom);

 g_Player = new C_Player();
 g_Player.setspeed(0.08, 0.8);

 jsSetEventHandlers();
 
 animate();
}

function jsSetEventHandlers() {
 window.addEventListener("resize", onWindowResize, false );

 window.addEventListener("keydown", onKeyDown, false);
 window.addEventListener("keyup", onKeyUp, false);
};

// Keyboard key down
function onKeyDown(e) {
 switch (e.keyCode) {
  case 37: // Left
  case 65: // A
   g_Player.keyleft = true;
   break;
  case 38: // Up
   g_Player.keyarrowup = true;
   break;
  case 87: // W
   g_Player.keyup = true;
   break;
  case 39: // Right
  case 68: // D
   g_Player.keyright = true;
   break;
  case 40: // Down
   g_Player.keyarrowdown = true;
   break;
  case 83: // S
   g_Player.keydown = true;
   break; 
 }
}

// Keyboard key up
function onKeyUp(e) {
 switch (e.keyCode) {
  case 37: // Left
  case 65: // A
   g_Player.keyleft = false;
   break;
  case 38: // Up
   g_Player.keyarrowup = false;
   break;
  case 87: // W
   g_Player.keyup = false;
   break;
  case 39: // Right
  case 68: // D
   g_Player.keyright = false;
   break;
  case 40: // Down
   g_Player.keyarrowdown = false;
   break;
  case 83: // S
   g_Player.keydown = false;
   break; 
 }
}

function onWindowResize() {
 g_Game.SCREEN_WIDTH = window.innerWidth;
 g_Game.SCREEN_HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;
 g_Game.aspect = g_Game.SCREEN_WIDTH / g_Game.SCREEN_HEIGHT;
 g_Game.renderer.setSize(g_Game.SCREEN_WIDTH, g_Game.SCREEN_HEIGHT);
 g_Game.cameraPerspective.aspect = 1 * g_Game.aspect;
 g_Game.cameraPerspective.updateProjectionMatrix();
}

function animate() {
 requestAnimationFrame(animate);
 //g_Game.stats.begin();

 render();

 //g_Game.stats.end();
}

function render() {
 g_Player.update();
 g_Game.renderer.render(g_Game.scene, g_Game.cameraPerspective);
}

//Classes
var C_Player = function() {
 this.ANGULAR_SPEED_MOVEMENT = 0.8;
 this.ANGULAR_SPEED_ROTATION = 0.08;

 this.keyleft = false;
 this.keyright = false;
 this.keyup = false;
 this.keydown = false;
 this.keyarrowup = false;
 this.keyarrowdown = false;
 this.QuatKeyU;
 this.QuatKeyD;
 this.QuatKeyL;
 this.QuatKeyR;
 
 this.setspeed = function(speedM, speedR) {
  this.ANGULAR_SPEED_MOVEMENT = speedM;
  this.ANGULAR_SPEED_ROTATION = speedR;
  this.QuatKeyU = new THREE.Quaternion().setFromAxisAngle(new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 0), -(this.ANGULAR_SPEED_MOVEMENT*Math.PI) / 180);
  this.QuatKeyD = new THREE.Quaternion().setFromAxisAngle(new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 0),  (this.ANGULAR_SPEED_MOVEMENT*Math.PI) / 180);
  this.QuatKeyL = new THREE.Quaternion().setFromAxisAngle(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1),  (this.ANGULAR_SPEED_ROTATION*Math.PI) / 180);
  this.QuatKeyR = new THREE.Quaternion().setFromAxisAngle(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1), -(this.ANGULAR_SPEED_ROTATION*Math.PI) / 180);
 }

 var qx;
 var qy;
 var qz;
 var qw;
 var rotWorldMatrix;

 this.update = function(seconds) {
  var rlud = false;

  if (this.keyup) {
   g_Game.cubePlayer.quaternion.multiply(this.QuatKeyU);
   g_Game.cameraPerspective.quaternion.multiply(this.QuatKeyU);
   rlud = true;
  } else if (this.keydown) {
   g_Game.cubePlayer.quaternion.multiply(this.QuatKeyD);
   g_Game.cameraPerspective.quaternion.multiply(this.QuatKeyD);
   rlud = true;
  };
  if (this.keyleft) {
   g_Game.cubePlayer.quaternion.multiply(this.QuatKeyL);
   g_Game.cameraPerspective.quaternion.multiply(this.QuatKeyL);
   rlud = true;
  } else if (this.keyright) {
   g_Game.cubePlayer.quaternion.multiply(this.QuatKeyR);
   g_Game.cameraPerspective.quaternion.multiply(this.QuatKeyR);
   rlud = true;
  };

  if (rlud == true) {
   qx = g_Game.cubePlayer.quaternion.x;
   qy = g_Game.cubePlayer.quaternion.y;
   qz = g_Game.cubePlayer.quaternion.z;
   qw = g_Game.cubePlayer.quaternion.w;
   g_Game.cubePlayer.position.x = 2 * (qy * qw + qz * qx) * 105;
   g_Game.cubePlayer.position.y = 2 * (qz * qy - qw * qx) * 105;
   g_Game.cubePlayer.position.z = ((qz * qz + qw * qw) - (qx * qx + qy * qy)) * 105;

   qx = g_Game.cameraPerspective.quaternion.x;
   qy = g_Game.cameraPerspective.quaternion.y;
   qz = g_Game.cameraPerspective.quaternion.z;
   qw = g_Game.cameraPerspective.quaternion.w;
   g_Game.cameraPerspective.position.x = 2 * (qy * qw + qz * qx) * g_Game.cameraDistance;
   g_Game.cameraPerspective.position.y = 2 * (qz * qy - qw * qx) * g_Game.cameraDistance;
   g_Game.cameraPerspective.position.z = ((qz * qz + qw * qw) - (qx * qx + qy * qy)) * g_Game.cameraDistance;
    }
  
  if (this.keyarrowup) {
   var q = new THREE.Quaternion().setFromAxisAngle(new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 0), -(this.ANGULAR_SPEED_MOVEMENT*Math.PI*10) / 180);
   arrowHelper.quaternion.multiply(q);
  }
  if (this.keyarrowdown) {
   var q = new THREE.Quaternion().setFromAxisAngle(new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 0), (this.ANGULAR_SPEED_MOVEMENT*Math.PI*10) / 180);
   arrowHelper.quaternion.multiply(q);
  }
 }
}

function C_Game() {
 this.SCREEN_WIDTH = window.innerWidth;
 this.SCREEN_HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;
 this.aspect = this.SCREEN_WIDTH / this.SCREEN_HEIGHT;
 this.container;
 this.stats;
 this.scene;
 this.renderer;
 this.earth;
 this.cubePlayer;
 this.controls;
 this.cameraPerspective;
 this.cameraDistance = 125;
 this.cubeaxis = new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 0);
}
```

```css
#divScreen {
 position: absolute;
 left: 0%;
 top: 0%;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 overflow: auto;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 border: 0px; 
 background-color: #AACCFF;
 overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
<div id="divScreen"></div>
```

Comment: That was like Colombus' egg, right in front my of eyes. Thank you so much. Btw, is there a way of determining that the arrowhelper is at 180 degrees (zenith) or 0 degrees(nadir), so that I can stop the rotation when it reaches these two points?

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out, I will just sum to a variable the rotation delta each time the event is fired.